# Correctly use Dependency Injection pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm using the Unity IoC container.

Composition root:

```
   Container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   Container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   Container.RegisterType<IMyClass2, MyClass2>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

`IService` injected to `MyClass`.

```
 public class MyClass : IMyClass
 {
        private readonly IService  _service;

        public MyClass(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        void Do()
        {
            //get List<MyClass>
            var result = _service.GetData();

            var list = new List<IMyClass2>();

            // convert to List<IMyClass2>
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                var myClass2 = Container.Resolve<IMyClass2>();
                myClass2.Data = item;
                list.Add(myClass2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is `MyClass` knows about the container (to resolve `IMyClass2`). Is this incorrectly using dependency injection?

How to correctly solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

**Solution**

The solution is based on the Wiktor Zychla [post](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/di-factories-and-composition-root.html) .

Add new dependency to MyClass.

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
 {
        private readonly IService  _service;
        private readonly IMyClass2Factory _myClass2Factory;

        public MyClass(IService service, IMyClass2Factory myClass2Factory)
        {
            _service = service;
            _myClass2Factory = myClass2Factory;
        }

        void Do()
        {
            //get List<MyClass>
            var result = _service.GetData();

            var list = new List<IMyClass2>();

            // convert to List<IMyClass2>
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                var myClass2 = _myClass2Factory.Create();
                myClass2.Data = item;
                list.Add(myClass2);
            }
        }
 }
```

Abstract factory.

```
public interface IMyClass2Factory() 
{
    IMyClass2 Create();
}
```

Concrete factory with dependency `Unity` container.

```
public class MyClass2Factory : IMyClass2Factory
{
   private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

   public MyClass2Factory(IUnityContainer container)
   {
       _container = container;
   }

   IMyClass2 Create()
   {
      return _container.Resolve<IMyClass2>();
   }
}
```

And composition root:

```
   Container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   Container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   Container.RegisterType<IMyClass2, MyClass2>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   Container.RegisterInstance<IMyClass2Factory>(new IMyClass2Factory(Container));
```

At first it may seem that we have moved the problem to another location.

But it agile solution and now `MyClass` not depend on the container and can use different configuration, e.g. on Unit test project.

IMHO depend on the abstract factory is the lesser of two evils.

Comment: Just as an FYI the code you have is not a DI pattern,it is called 'Service locator' pattern.

Comment: Resolving IMyClass2 like 'Service locator', but is not 'Service locator'

Comment: @Alexandr: just read the answer on Dependency Resolvers aka Local Factories from the question I marked yours as the duplicate of.

Comment: I will get acquainted with the material, if not find the answer, I'll update my question. Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorZychla: please, check my update, I understand your idea?

Comment: @Alexandr: almost. You see, you don't have to pass the factory there. Rather, you just use a concrete factory, it doesn't have to implement the interface. It is the opposite, everyone knows the concrete factory but this is the Composition Root that **configures** the factory, i.e. sets the internal implementation to use Unity or anything else, depending on your needs.